# PHP exec or shell_exec not returning process id (PID) on Windows Wamp

Tags: php, windows, ffmpeg, shell-exec, pid

I am on windows 7, using a WampServer, and trying to use FFMPEG.

The encoding works, but I can't get a process id back from either the `exec()`
method nor the `shell_exec()` methods.

This is my code :

```
$cmd = C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i "C:\...\4ch.wav"  -ar 44100 -ab 48000 -f mp3 -y "C:\...\enc_4ch.mp3"
```

This what I was trying to do with shell_exec :

```
shell_exec("nohup $cmd > /dev/null & echo $!");
```

And with exec :

```
exec("nohup " . $this->_command . " > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &") ; // returns null
exec("nohup " . $this->_command . " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"); // also returns null
```

Please let me know what I do wrong, as I'd like later to use the following method to check if my process is still running :

```
private function is_process_running($proccess_id) 
    { 
        exec("ps $proccess_id", $process_state);
        return (count($process_state) >= 2);
    }
```

thank you in advace

Answer (score 0):

You are using `echo $!` to get the process ID, and that specific command is not available on Windows as it is a *unix shell* command. The procedure link should work: [How to get PID from PHP function exec() in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679663/how-to-get-pid-from-php-function-exec-in-windows)

Comment: you mean by using the `tasklist` ?