# Get pid from exec() in php

Tags: php, exec, pid

I need to exec a script using exec() and get the pid back.

```
$pid = exec("./runtunnel $remoteip $remoteport $localport");
```

Answer (score 3):

in unix, you can add this to get only the PID:

```
$command = $yourCommand . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!'; 
exec($command, $output);
$pid = (int)$output[0];
```

hope that will be helpful :)

Comment: The last line should be `$pid = (int)$output[0];`

Comment: will it wait till the execution ends? I don't think so

Comment: @FlashThunder, ` &` means it was started in background. After that `echo $!` will be executed and it returns last PID. Furthermore `exec` returns last line from the output, so no need to get PID from the `$output`. Just execute `$pid = exec('command > /dev/nul/ 2>&1 & echo $!')`

Comment: that is not true :)

Answer (score -2):

Actuall code for execute command is here:

```
exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

so to get output you need to add second argument:

```
$pid = exec("./runtunnel $remoteip $remoteport $localport",$output);
```

`$output` will have the output.

[reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: @user3722254 check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679663/how-to-get-pid-from-php-function-exec-in-windows